# Extending JSF commandLink component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I created a Facelet component to extend h:commandLink (to add some functionality and rounded corners).

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <span class="btn-left btn-corners">&#160;</span>
    <span type="submit" class="submit">
        <h:commandLink id="#{id}" value="#{label}" action="#{action}" />
    </span>
    <span class="btn-right btn-corners">&#160;</span> </ui:composition>
```

My new component can be accessed using

```
<my:commandLink id="continue" label="continue" action="#{applyBacking.submit}"/>
```

and the Java code is

```
public String submit(){
    ...
}
```

However it gives me an error "ApplyBacking does not have the property submit". 
I understand the reason for this error because while rendering my:commandLink, it tries to evaluate #{applyBacking.submit} to a property. Instead, I want the info about the method to the invoked (applyBacking.submit) to be passed to the template and evaluated while rendering h:commandLink.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a [composite component](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/composite/tld-summary.html) instead ([tutorial here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html)), it enables you to define bean actions as attribtues.

Here's a kickoff example:

`/resources/components/commandLink.xhtml`

```
<ui:component
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="id" required="true" />
        <cc:attribute name="label" required="true" />
        <cc:attribute name="action" method-signature="java.lang.String action()" required="true" />
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        <span class="btn-left btn-corners">&#160;</span>
        <span type="submit" class="submit">
            <h:commandLink id="#{cc.attrs.id}" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" action="#{cc.attrs.action}" />
        </span>
        <span class="btn-right btn-corners">&#160;</span>
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

`/somepage.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components">
    <h:head>
        <title>SO question 4608030</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <my:commandLink id="continue" label="continue" action="#{applyBacking.submit}"/>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

By the way, I would personally prefer using JS/jQuery for the rounded corners part, for example the [jQuery corner plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/). Just give your commandlink a specific `styleClass` and let JS do the magic.